# Java EE webapp not creating files/folders

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE webapp that works perfectly when I run it on Eclipse and my local tomcat server (I've also tested on a friend's tomcat server), but not on a production server.

This is the problem: The app is supposed to create a folder at a specific location (I've tried hardcoding this as well), but when run on the production server, it doesn't create it and throws no exceptions that it was unable to create it. Later on in the code when it's trying to use those files, it complains that they don't exist.

I thought this could be a process permission issue, although I start the tomcat server in init.d using sudo, so the process should be root and have no permission problems! If you have any thoughts on this, I would love to hear them. Thanks a lot guys.

p.s. All the computers I've tested on are Max OS X(10.5.6) and the production server is RedHat Linux (Unsure of version, but quite recent).

Comment: Other than the OS, what is different about your production environment?

Comment: I was gonna guess permission problems...

Comment: What is the absolute path of the folder on the filesystem and the permissions on that folder, e.g. (drwxr-xr-x)?

Comment: Hi, thanks all for the suggestions. 
The tomcat servers are both the same, but the Java versions are not, simply because the Mac Java version is apparently totally different? 
I'm not aware of any other differences between the environments. 

The absolute path is /home/myusername/jcrrepo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas that could help :

- check potential differences of version between local and production tomcat
- check the same upon java versions and how it manages security
- check that no other processing deletes the directory / file created by the process you're concerned with (it could sound stupid, but sometimes you can be surprised...)
- add a piece of code just after the directory creation that execs and logs a "ls -l " just as an additional visual control